# Data sent in ajax call

Tags: ajax

From what I understand, an Ajax call is a request that goes from a browser client side (javascript) to the server side (php). This request can be accompanied by some data that we need to send from our client side to the server side. And then afterwards, the server can respond, and send some data back from the server side to the client side.
I saw the following syntax when I was surfing the web:
My question is is the `data` variable in `success: function (data) {` can be called response or result ? right? it is the data that the server sends back to the client side and it is different from the data in data: `{'date': 18-7-2021},` which is the data sent originally from the client side to server side. Is that correct? maybe the names confused me a bit.

```
  url: "/find-news-by-date",
  method: 'POST',
  data: {'date': 18-7-2021},
  success: function (data) {
    var contentblock= $("#display-data-news");
    contentblock.val(data['news']);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the data that the server sends back to the client side and it is different from the data in data: {'date': 18-7-2021} that you sent from the client to the server.

To avoid confusion, you can modify your code to:

```
 url: "/find-news-by-date",
  method: 'POST',
  data: {'date': 18-7-2021},
  success: function (response) {
    var contentblock= $("#display-data-news");
    contentblock.val(response['news']);
    }
});
```